# I was trying to add id number in the same field with express js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```
{
  _id:64075739ffe03167433f973e, 
  email:"sfg@gmail.com", 
  number:"1222222", 
  name:"sfg", 
  id:"642348ec6c048643eea776f6"
}
```

I was trying to add more number string to be stored in id section when the user will click on a button.
When the user click on a button with a id of "642348d36c048643eea776f4" ,this id needs to be stored with the previous one as an array element.As for example :

```
{
  _id:64075739ffe03167433f973e, 
  email:"sfg@gmail.com", 
  number:"1222222", 
  name:"sfg", 
  id:["642348ec6c048643eea776f6", "642348d36c048643eea776f4",....],
}
```

After every button click the size of the array should be increased with a new value.

```
try{
        const db = getDb();
        const email = req.params.email;
        const role = req.body;
        const query = {email : email};
        const updatedDoc = {
            $set:role,
        }
        const result = await db.collection('users').update(query,updatedDoc);
        res.json(result)
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
```

I am using this blocks(Express.js and mongoDb) of code but it can only update.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `req.body` contains the `_id` you need to add, you should [`$push`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) the new value:

```
const result = await db.collection('users').update({ email }, { $push: { role: req.body._id } });
```